# Are ganglion cells in the foveal avascular zone served by choroidal blood supply or diffusion from retinal layer capillary beds?

Tags: neuroscience, anatomy, human-eye

I am trying to determine which blood supply (choroidal or retinal) serves the retinal ganglion cells that respond to foveal cone stimulation. I know that the fovea is supplied by the choroid, but it is unclear to me if this only applies to the cones in the fovea. The paper I link to below mentions that the choroid serves the fovea, but the choroid also serves the outer retina in total (and the RPE). So is the statement that 'the choroid serves the fovea' extending beyond the observation that the choroid serves the outer retina (since the fovea is mostly cones due to the inner layers being pushed aside)?

Are the ganglion cells that are pushed aside in the fovea served by choroidal vessels, or are they pushed aside far enough to be served by capillaries in the retinal layers? Please provide a paper as a reference.

I've searched google obviously and perused PubMed and I cannot find a clear answer to this.

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK482301/

Comment: I'm sorry if this sounds picky, but did you enter your question into a decent search engine? Also, your title and your actual question don't seem to me to match. You seem aware that there are ganglion cells in the FAZ, and it's the blood supply that you ask about in your final question. Would you please edit for clarity?